# How to optimize this MiniZinc app?

Tags: optimization, minizinc

I have a MiniZinc app where I want to minimize the "cost" of something by finding a low-cost permutation of some input data. So I have:

```
array[1 .. n] of var 1 .. n: Seq;
...
constraint alldifferent( [ Seq[i] | i in 1 .. n ]);
```

And then I compute cost based on Seq. The app is starting to work but runs too long for n more than a very small number. Apparently the solver tries all n! possibilities. How do I scale this?

Comment: Hi Jim. The high complexity is unavoidable, some heuristic, like LNS, is required. I'm also exploring the QCSP field (quantified constraints solving), with Gecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If alldifferent(Seq) is the only constraint then the solver will try all the permutations.

However, often there are symmetries in the permutation that might be possible to break, for example that the first element is 1 or that the first element always is less than the second element etc. These kind of symmetries are often very problem specific.

If there are other constraints in the model, then these can help to reduce the search space, perhaps by breaking symmetries etc.

How large are n in the normal case? As usual, more details of the model help to give a more specific help. Also, trying different solvers and search heuristics can speed things up.

Comment: Thanks. There are other constraints but from your reply I am starting to understand that the other constraints are mostly related to the computation of cost and so they don't limit the permutation search. However I was hoping that MiniZinc would do something like a simulated annealing approach to find a "good" permutation. n will be in the ballpark of 50. This is a scheduling problem.

Comment: Is there some way to do what I want?

Comment: There is no simulated annealing or local search built in MiniZinc's default solvers. Some "advanced" solvers can be faster, for example the experimental OscaR CBLS solver that use Constraint-Based local search (https://bitbucket.org/oscarlib/oscar/wiki/Home/ ). In the latest Gecode version has support for "simple form of LNS accessible from FlatZinc" but I haven't tested this and I don't know if it help in your case. See http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/PageChange.html#SectionChanges_4_3_3

Comment: Since this is a scheduling problem, perhaps you can use other constraints, e.g. cumulative etc? As mentioned earlier, just using alldifferent will make the search tree very large.

Comment: Jim, if you send me the full model (including data) I can take a quick look and see if I can see any "obvious" improvement.